# the ideal structure of group $C^*$-algebras

Tags: fourier-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

What is the ideal structure of group $C^*$-algebras? Do there exist any books or articles in the field ?
If G to be the group of integers $Z$ , then $C^*$($Z$)=C($T$). so because ideal structure of C(X) characterized then it is trivial ! The conditions on the G in mind , is locally compact group or finite group or totally disconnected compactly generated locally compact groups?

Comment: $C^*$(G)=cl$L^1(G)$?  G is locally compact group

Comment: Salam Mehrdad. What do you mean $C^*(G)=cl L^1(G)$ ? Any way, the group $C^*(G)$ is the norm closure of $\pi(L^1(G))$ where $\pi$ is  the universal representation of $L^1(G)$ i.e, direct sum of all non-degenerate representations.

Comment: Salam.Dear Prof.Bagheri :Your comment is exact.thanks you for your explain .